# The scope of this variables

Tags: java, variables, scope

I have this code :

```
public Thread createThread(){
     final int innerVar = 100;   //this Life cycle ?
     return new Thread(){
          public void run(){
             System.out.println(innerVar);
          }
     };
}
```

and I want to know what is the Life cycle of `innerVar`?

The local variable of `innerVar` whether still in stack or in heap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`innerVar` is a constant `int`, so the compiler can perform constant propagation. There is no life cycle, because the `value` is used instead of a *variable*.

Comment: How does Java handle it internally ? As we know that final variable can be initialized only once. But if I call that method twice it will be initialized twice

Comment: @Rehman It isn't a variable, the compiler is free to replace every `innerVar` with `100`. Thus, at run-time, [*there is no spoon*](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThereIsNoSpoon).